# iOS React native upgrade build issue

Tags: ios, react-native

Xcode 12.4, React native version 0.64.2

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UMModuleRegistryProvider", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UMModuleRegistryAdapter", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

2021-08-09 21:41:56.689 xcodebuild[95751:1923492]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-17800/DVTFoundation/Utilities/DVTFileSystemUtilities.mm:142
Details:  lstat('/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core-60309c9c/AccessibilityResources.bundle') failed with errno 2 (No such file or directory)
Function: DVTRecursiveMkdirResult dvt_recursiveMkdir_returningErrorString(NSString *__strong, NSString *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7feecc1229c0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Are you using an M1 mac?

Comment: No, Intel Mac only

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own quesiton.

In the react-native@0.64.2. react-native-adapter is an independent module. the pod file is like this

```
  pod 'UMReactNativeAdapter', path: '../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios', inhibit_warnings: true
```

Also, it also requires updates in react-native-unimodules.